# get() returned more than one Post -- it returned 2

Tags: python, django, generics, coinbase-api

I got problem in django. Im creating online shop website and I add products section where my products listed(html). I add my products from admin site (models.py).
When I want to add to products i give error like this : get() returned more than one Post -- it returned 2!

These are my codes :

**views.py**

```
class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "shop-single.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        models = Post.objects.get()
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        client = Client(api_key = settings.COINBASE_COMMERCE_API_KEY)
        domain_url = "https://www.nitroshop.store/"
        product = {"name" : f'{models.title}' , 'description': f'{models.subject}' ,  "local_price" : {'amount' : f'{models.product_price}' , "currency" : "USD"} , "pricing_type" : "fixed_price" , "redirect_url" : domain_url + "NXnUijYpLIPy4xz4isztwkwAqSXOK89q3GEu5DreA3Ilkde2e93em8TUe99oRz64UWWBw9gEiiZrg60GMu3ow" , "cancel_url" : domain_url + "products"}
        charge = client.charge.create(**product)
        context['charge'] = charge
        return context
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

STATUS = (
    (0 , "Draft"),
    (1 , "Publish")
)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200 , unique = True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 200 , unique = True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User , on_delete = models.CASCADE , related_name = "shop_posts")
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length = 200 , default = "We offer you pay with Tether or Litecoin")
    caption = models.TextField()
    product_brand = models.CharField(max_length = 200 , default = "Add parametr")
    product_price = models.CharField(max_length = 200 , default = "Add parametr")
    opt = models.TextField(default = "Add parametr")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = "images/" , default = "None")
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices = STATUS , default = 0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-created_on"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I must be use coinbase gateway for payment. I want when user go to coinbase payment the title of product(each product title) set on coinbase title and ...
But I have error like that when i want add more products

Would you please help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
models = Post.objects.get()
```

This method is to `get()` a single object from model. If you don't apply any parameters, then it tries to get all objects in `QuerySet`. If there is more than one (or None), then it will throw an error. And this is happening, because I can assume you have two `Post` objects in your database.

You need to pass parameter like:

```
models = Post.objects.get(id=some_id)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I solved this problem with Post.objects.all() on for loop